# Can I keep players of dead characters engaged in Dread?

Tags: gm-techniques, dread

I've ran one or two games of Dread at roleplaying conventions, and I really liked the tension the system generates.

However, players want to be involved to the very end. Is there anything I can do to keep the players of dead characters involved?